# Let pi-hole fetch its IP from DHCP

Tags: pi-hole

I want to configure my pi-hole to use my routers DHCP instead of setting a static IP. And before you say "you need a static IP", I know, but the DHCP server running on my UDM Pro already has a fixed IP configured for the raspberry so it will always get the same IP and there is no need for pi-hole to set a static IP on the system itself.

Is there no way to tell pi-hole to get its IP from the DHCP?

`pi-hole` seems to always overwrite my `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` and insert a static IP setting as specified when setting up `pi-hole`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to dump `pi-hole` and get a better adblock DNS like

- [AdGuardHome](https://github.com/AdguardTeam/AdGuardHome)
- or [grimd](https://github.com/looterz/grimd)

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your request...

> Is there no way to tell pi-hole to get its IP from the DHCP?

Which DHCP? the routeur dhcp or pihole dhcp ?

Would you like your router to assign a different ip to each reboot

If yes, remove the dhcp reservation from your router.

If not, leave it

Or if you want an ip you choose, go to the router's dhcp reservation and change the assigned ip to the one you want (be careful that it is not already assigned to another device.